# How can I set the expired time in node oAuth2 Server

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I am currently working on a little project with oAuth2 with node js.
Node js with express and node-oauth2-server as a rest full service to login etc...

Everything is working just fine, they can register, verify their email address and login (forgott password etc. is not finished yet)
But I can not set the expire value of the token.

My favourite implementation would be a login with or without permanent login (in the UI this common little switch beneath the login form).
Also I would like to store the client information with the accessToken, something like Browser, Location etc.
So that a user can request where he is currently logged in (like you can do in facebook).

Most of my oAuth2 code comes from this tutorial:
https://blog.cloudboost.io/how-to-make-an-oauth-2-server-with-node-js-a6db02dc2ce7

My main problem is, that I don't know where to handle the data. In my register (etc.) endpoints everything runs through my own middleware. But with the node-oauth2-server I have no middleware.

Thanks!

Chris

Here is my server.js:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined)
    process.env.NODE_ENV = "dev"


/* REQUIRE */
const oAuth2Server = require('node-oauth2-server');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const util = require('util');
const dbCon = require('./subsystem/mySql')
const oAuthModel = require('./endpoints/auth/authModel')(dbCon);

/* CONST */
let port = 3000;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')
    port = 3000;
else
    port = 80;
const debug = true;
const app = express();

/* INIT */
app.oauth = oAuth2Server({
    model: oAuthModel,
    grants: ['password'],
    debug: debug
})

/* ROUTER */
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(app.oauth.errorHandler());

const authRoutes = require('./router/auth')(express.Router(), app, dbCon)
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send({message: "This service was not found"});
});

/* Start Server */
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${port} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode`)
})
```

Here is my authModel:

```
let dbCon;
module.exports = injectedDbCon => {
    dbCon = injectedDbCon;
    return {
        getClient: getClient,
        saveAccessToken: saveAccessToken,
        getUser: getUser,
        grantTypeAllowed: grantTypeAllowed,
        getAccessToken: getAccessToken
    }
}

const userDB = require('../user/userDB')(dbCon);
const authDB = require('./authDB');

function getClient(clientID, clientSecret, callback){

    const client = {
        clientID,
        clientSecret,
        grants: null,
        redirectUris: null
    }

    callback(false, client);
}

function grantTypeAllowed(clientID, grantType, callback) {

    console.log('grantTypeAllowed called and clientID is: ', clientID, ' and grantType is: ', grantType);

    callback(false, true);
}


function getUser(email, password, callback){

    console.log('getUser() called and email is: ', email, ' and password is: ', password, ' and callback is: ', callback, ' and is userDBHelper null is: ', userDB);

    //try and get the user using the user's credentials
    userDB.getUserFromCrentials(email, password)
    .then(data => {callback(false,data[0][0])})
    .catch(error => {callback(error,null)})
}

/* saves the accessToken along with the userID retrieved the specified user */
function saveAccessToken(accessToken, clientID, expires, user, callback){

    console.log('saveAccessToken() called and accessToken is: ', accessToken,
        ' and clientID is: ',clientID, ' and user is: ', user, ' and accessTokensDBhelper is: ', authDB)

    //save the accessToken along with the user.id
    authDB.saveAccessToken(accessToken, user.id)
    .then(data => {callback(null)})
    .catch(error => {callback(error)})

}

function getAccessToken(bearerToken, callback) {

    //try and get the userID from the db using the bearerToken
    authDB.getUserIDFromBearerToken(bearerToken)
    .then(data => {
        const accessToken = {
            user: {
                id: data,
            },
            expires: null
        }
        callback(true,accessToken)
    })
    .catch(error => {callback(false,error)})
}
```

Here is my authDB:

```
const dbCon = require('../../subsystem/mySql')

const saveAccessToken = (accessToken, userID) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        //execute the query to get the user
        dbCon.query(`INSERT INTO access_tokens (access_token, user_id) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE access_token = ?;`,[accessToken,userID,accessToken])
        .then(data => {resolve(true)})
        .catch(error => {reject(error)})
    })
}


const getUserIDFromBearerToken = bearerToken => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        //create query to get the userID from the row which has the bearerToken
        const getUserIDQuery = `SELECT * FROM access_tokens WHERE access_token = ?;`

        //execute the query to get the userID
        dbCon.query(getUserIDQuery,[bearerToken])
        .then(data => {
            if(data.results != null && data.results.length == 1)
                resolve(data.results[0].user_id)
            else
                reject(false)
        })
        .catch(error => {reject(error)})
    })
}


module.exports.saveAccessToken = saveAccessToken
module.exports.getUserIDFromBearerToken = getUserIDFromBearerToken
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass *accessTokenLifetime* (in seconds) as option to the oAuth2Server constructor.

```
/* INIT */
app.oauth = oAuth2Server({
    model: oAuthModel,
    grants: ['password'],
    debug: debug,
    accessTokenLifetime: 4 * 60 * 60
})
```

As descripted in the docs (https://oauth2-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/oauth2-server.html#new-oauth2server-options) you can pass any option for the *authenticate*, *authorize* and *token* methods to the oAuth2Server constructors options.

The *accessTokenLifetime* option is an option of the token method (https://oauth2-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/oauth2-server.html#token-request-response-options-callback).